# Kubernetes how to create a sidecar which runs initialization and terminate

Tags: kubernetes, initialization, sleep, execution

I need a sidecar in kubernetes cluster which runs initialization script and then terminates or sleep forever. I can't do this in postStart as postStart does not guarantee the CMD / ENTRYPOINT in main container has started. Any advice and insight is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [Init Containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Job to accomplish the task.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
```